# List path with word match in bash script

Tags: bash

I have a string that contain a list of lines.I want to search any particular string and list all the path that contains the string.
The given string contains the following:

```
  755677 myfile/Edited-WAV-Files
  756876 orignalfile/videofile
  758224 orignalfile/audiofile
  758224 orignalfile/photos 
  758225 others/video
  758267 others/photo 
  758268 orignalfile/videofile1
  758780 others/photo1
```

I want to extract and list only the path that start from Orignal File. My output should be like this:

```
 756876 orignalfile/videofile
 758224 orignalfile/audiofile
 758224 orignalfile/photos 
 758268 orignalfile/videofile1
```

Comment: Please improve your question by posting some [properly formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) code you've applied to the problem. Also, include a properly-formatted sample of your **expected output** so folks understand the results you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

That looks easy enough...

```
echo "$string" | grep originalfile/
```

or

```
grep originalfile/ << eof
$string
eof
```

or, if it's in a file,

```
grep originalfile/ sourcefile
```

Comment: or `grep originalfile/ <<<"$string"`

Comment: Well, yes, the question *is* tagged *bash*, but I try to stick with Posix sh anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A bash solution:

```
while read f1 f2
do
     [[ "$f2" =~ ^orignal ]] && echo $f1 $f2
done < file
```

Comment: I don't think that would match any of the lines, since they all start with numbers, and none start with "orignal".

Comment: @PhilFrost, Guru is only matching against the 2nd field, not the whole line

Answer (score 0):

If your string spans several lines like this:

```
755677 myfile/Edited-WAV-Files
756876 orignalfile/videofile
758224 orignalfile/audiofile
758224 orignalfile/photos
758225 others/video
758267 others/photo
758268 orignalfile/videofile1
758780 others/photo1
```

Then you can use this code:

```
echo "$(echo "$S" | grep -F ' orignalfile/')"
```

If the string is not separated by new lines then

```
echo $S | grep -oE "[0-9]+ orignalfile/[^ ]+"
```

Comment: It is not separated by lines and i used this command grep  -oE "[0-9]+ ZR66.*" /Users/backupuser/Desktop/test.rtf, but some how it is not listing this content (755676   ZR66_op/Res-Edited-MP3-Files) out of  755676   ZR66_op/Res-Edited-MP3-Files 
755677 ZR66_op/Res-Files  
756876 ZR66_op/Res-Edited-WAV-Files 
758228 ZR67_op/Res5.fcp 
all others are getting listed. can you help me.

Comment: Try `grep -oE "[0-9]+ ZR66[^ ]+" your_file`

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep '^[0-9]{6} orignalfile/' <<<"$string"
```

note:

- the `^` matches the start of the string. You don't want to match things that happen to have `orignalfile/` somewhere in the middle
- `[0-9]{6}` matches the six digits at the start of each line

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your string contains linebreaks/newlines?
If it does then the solution of DigitalRoss will apply.

If it doesn't contain newlines then you must include them. In example if your code looks like

```
string=$(ls -l)
```

then you must prepend it with field separator string without linefeed:

```
IFS=$'\t| ' string=$(ls -l)
```

or with an empty IFS var:

```
IFS='' string=$(ls -l)
```

Docs for IFS from the bash man page:

```
IFS    The  Internal  Field  Separator  that  is  used for word splitting after
       expansion and to split lines into words with the read builtin command.  The
       default value is ``<space><tab><newline>''.
```